# Can't recreate Word DOCX document after manually hacking part of its XML contents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, xml

I have a Word DOCX document (not sure what version of Word it was created with). I am having problems printing it to a local printer or into PDF. In the latter case, it complains about one of the fonts (`Cambria`, that I think is used for math equations in the document). Since DOCX is just a ZIP archive, I decide to hack the document by manually replacing mentions of the font with another font name in one of the XML files that comprise the DOCX. However, once I zipped up the folder into a new DOCX document, it failed to load into Word. I first tried it with `7zip` as follows:

```
7z a new_document.docx new_document
```

where `new_document` is the folder containing all the pieces included the manually modified XML file. I got `MS Office can't open this file because the zip archive file is an unsupported version`. Then I tried

```
zip -r new_document.docx new_document
```

and got `MS Office can't open this file because some parts are missing or invalid`.

Even though my changes were minimal, it's possible that I messed something up. Still, is there a "right" way to compress the document folder back into a valid DOCX?

Comment: IIRC the/some files need to be in a specific order in the ZIP archive. Also make sure you’re not accidentally creating a subfolder in the archive that contains everything.

Comment: @DanielB You're right! I was creating an extra folder when zipping. After I fixed it and used `zip` without any options other than `-r` I got a good DOCX back. My manual hack didn't work, though, but that's off-topic. I wish I could accept your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you call `7z` and `zip` is slightly wrong. It will result in a ZIP archive that has the `new_document` folder at the root level. However, you want `new_document`’s *contents* at the root level.

Additionally, I believe to remember that you cannot use all ZIP features with Office Open XML and that (some) files need to appear in a specific order in the archive. Take that with a grain of salt though.